# Batch that finds duplicate files, as well as the original

Tags: windows, batch, filesystems, cmd.exe

I am trying to clean up a drive of duplicate files, and have edited a batch I found that will list all duplicate files in a text document for me to review later, and determine which one to keep. 
   The issue I am currently having is that it lists all duplicate files, but it will not list the filepath of the original file. Ideally I would like the text file formatted like so:

Originalfile1
    -Copy1  size
    -Copy2  size
    -Copy3  size

Originalfile1
    -Copy1 size
    -Copy2 size

This is the batch I am currently using:

```
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set root="c:\users\devon\desktop\test"
set "prevTest=none"
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%A in (
  '"(for /r "%root%" %%F in (*) do @echo %%~nxF:%%~fF:)|sort"'
) do (
  set "currTest=%%A"      
  set size=%%~zC
  set "currFile=%%B:%%C"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  if !currTest! equ !prevTest! (
  >>C:\d\test.txt echo !currFile! : !size! Bytes
  )
  endlocal
  set "prevTest=%%A"
)
pause
```

I am still learning, but currently the closest I can get for format is

copy1
copy2
copy3
copy1
copy2

Comment: A much simpler way to do this is simply use from elevated command prompt this exactly and then look at the output and you can pipe all this to a log file later if needed to for review.... `robocopy "X:\source" "X:\destination" * /L >> X:\logfile` This will show you **newer files** in source that are not in destination, and it will also show you the **extra files** in the destination that are not in source. Everything else is shows as for file name and file size are all the duplicates... easy. done, and next... Let me know if you'd like more detail or a correlated answer added with this detail.

Comment: So `robocopy "X:\source" "X:\destination" * /L >> X:\logfile` as a one-liner can replace all that batch script looping, etc. Give it a shot and you may be surprised. See [robocopy](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: @Spittin'BigNastyIT, I can see where this would be useful, and I did leave this out of my original post, but I'm not sure if this will work how I'd like, as my end goal is to pass the filepaths as variables to powershell in order to create shortcuts to these files, to make things easier on the people who need to sift through this data and decide what needs to be kept.

Comment: I'd have to play with it a bit or your logic but I see what you're doing now passing the argument to PS script, etc. to create the shortcuts or what you need. May get a list with something like `robocopy .\source .\dest * /L /IS /FP /NS /NDL /NJH /NJS | FINDSTR /I /C:"Same">>Log.log` and then iterate thru that list for the full paths to pass to the PS script or whatever. It was just a quick idea anyway without a lot of thought and without understanding the rest, etc. Good luck... but to me without understanding a lot more, it seems you are making the batch way to complex for your ultimate goal